# Alarm manager not working for alarms scheduled after one hour

Tags: android, alarmmanager

All alarms scheduled before one hour works. Alarm scheduled after one hour does not work.

I am using below line to schedule alarm.

```
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeToAlarmMillis, pIntent);
```

I have written below code inside onReceive() method.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "AlarmBroadcaster");
wl.acquire();
String alarm_id = intent.getStringExtra("alarm_id");
createNotification(context, alarm_id);
wl.release();
```

Comment: can u explain this 'All alarms scheduled before one hour works.' ?

Comment: Eg. current time is 1 PM. If I schedule alarm before 2 PM ( at 1.05 PM or 1.30PM), alarm triggers fine. If I schedule it after 2PM ( at 2.05 PM or 2.30 PM), alarm does not get triggered.

Comment: All alarms scheduled before one hour works. Here I mean to say within one hour.

Comment: alright now i understand it :) , let me check it

Comment: Thanks quick learner. I found that my code is working now. I closed my project in android studio and the reopened it. After this I ran the application on my device and it worked. Thank you very much for giving your valuable time for this issue.

Comment: i am glad it worked dear , Happy coding :)